# Minikube installation failed in new MacOS Chip M1 - OS Big Sur

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, apple-m1, macos-big-sur

I am trying to install minikube on my mac os with M1 chip and following below guideline.

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/

I am running docker desktop 20.10.8 on my mac and getting the following error when I start minikube. Do I need to do anything for this to work on the new macos chip M1?

Here is the error

❌ Exiting due to K8S_APISERVER_MISSING: wait 6m0s for node: wait for apiserver proc: apiserver process never appeared  Suggestion: Check that the provided apiserver flags are valid, and that SELinux is disabled

Comment: Can you please update your question with exact commands you run to install `minikube` and how you started it? I wasn't able to reproduce it on macos with M1.

Comment: Ohh. Sorry !!! I was in some different things.  
I am following https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/ guideline and below is the command I am executing at my end. Are you able to install minikube successfully on MacOS with M1 ? Any specific guideline you are following ?
                                                                                                     
minikube start

Comment: @Koushik nothing specific, I run the installation steps for `macOS - arm64` and it worked fine on MacOS with M1 chip. This is why I asked for exact commands that were run. I also have the same docker desktop engine version `20.10.8`. Docker desktop itself is `4.1.1`

Comment: @moonkotte - thanks for the information. Let me check again and will keep you posted my findings. Though I was following the same steps with macOS - arm64.

Comment: @moonkotte - I have followed the steps, but received the below detailed error again. W1230 17:30:20.328816   89396 out.go:241] ❌  Problems detected in kubelet:
W1230 17:30:20.328857   89396 out.go:241]     Dec 30 11:54:33 minikube kubelet[3173]: E1230 11:54:33.226675    3173 reflector.go:138] object-"kube-system"/"kube-proxy": Failed to watch *v1.ConfigMap: failed to list *v1.ConfigMap: configmaps "kube-proxy" is forbidden: User "system:node:minikube" cannot list resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system": no relationship found between node 'minikube' and this object